# How to reproduce unique record based on a field value (date, account code) on data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, duplicate-management, unique-field

Lets say I have rows of sends on contacts on a data extension. These contacts can have the same value on the column Event Date, name and account code

This data extension would be like that :

```
Contact ID      EmailName         Date                AccountCode 
123             Email1            24/04/2022          12
124             Email1            24/04/2022          12
125             Email1            25/04/2022          12
126             Email2            25/04/2022          12
135             Email2            25/04/2022          13
136             Email2            26/04/2022          13
137             Email3            26/04/2022          13
138             Email3            27/04/2022          13
139             Email3            27/04/2022          13
```

I would like to deduplicate the rows to display one row (the first one) per EmailName, Date,  and AccountCode.

The results would be like that :

```
Contact ID      EmailName         Date                AccountCode 
123             Email1            24/04/2022          12
125             Email1            25/04/2022          12
126             Email2            25/04/2022          12
135             Email2            25/04/2022          13
136             Email2            26/04/2022          13
137             Email3            26/04/2022          13
139             Email3            27/04/2022          13
```

Comment: Do you want to implement this logic in Apex?

Comment: @Sneh, not it is to update a data extension in MarketingCloud

Comment: Have you tried writing the query @LT888?  If so, please update your question to include your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might exist more optimal ways to do this but i always return to this for these type of filtering.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties 
    [SubscriberKey], 
    EmailName,
    [EventDate],
    CodeGie
FROM [Reporting]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY EmailName, CodeGie, CONVERT(DATE, [EventDate]) 
    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, [EventDate]) ASC)
```

Edit: Edited per Adams comment below & with more info about query.

Comment: This won't work without adding an outer query.  You could use the shorthand version of this method: https://sprignaturemoves.com/picking-rows-with-partitions/

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs, I tried this code but it didn't work. I do have the error in QueryStudio "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.This is the code I tried ```select top 1 with ties   r.SubscriberKey   r.EventDate , r.CodeGIE , r.EmailName from Reporting order by row_number() over (partition by r.EmailName, r.EventDate order by date())```

Comment: Don't use Query Studio.

Comment: Hi @Adam Spriggs, I have put this code in the automation and it seemed to work : `SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties
    [SubscriberKey],
    EmailName,
    [EventDate],
    CodeGie
FROM [Reporting] x
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmailName, CodeGie, [EventDate] ORDER BY [EventDate] ASC)`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I have put this code in the automation but I still have multiple rows for the same EventDate  : ```SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties  [SubscriberKey], EmailName,[EventDate], CodeGieFROM [Reporting] x ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmailName, CodeGie, [EventDate] ORDER BY [EventDate] ASC)```. The issue is that my EventDate is with the format Month/Day/Year and Time Stamp like this Apr 25 2022  5:11PM.If I have two different times in the day for the same Code Gie, it will returns two rows. I think I have to change the format on a new field and change the EventDate in my request

Comment: @LT888 updated the answer above, converting datetime into date, you can also add this to the `SELECT` statement if you want to summarise on dates rather than datetime. In your last comment, your query had weird formatting and `CodeGie` was together with `FROM`, make sure to double check the formatting :)

Comment: @Alex, thanks a lot it worked !